# How to transfer data from excel to a website and print a result for each input?

Tags: python

I am trying to transfer data from an excel spread sheet. The data transferred is a 16 digit number and if the the number matches a user it prints his logins and the page changes. If the number does not match it returns nothing.

This is what i have done so far

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Import row A into string A array
data = pd.read_excel(r'document path')
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Code'])
print(df)

#Connect to website
#import requests
url ='url'
values= {'username' : ' ',
         'password' : ' '}
r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print ("r.content")


url ='url'
for (int i =0 =, i< string.a)
values= {'No' : ' df[1]',
         }
r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print ("r.content")
```

Comment: Basically, that is the code i have pulled from other people that have attempted to do this. I am learning at the minute so i am just following what people before me have done and learning as i go. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are facing. You have just described what you are trying to do. But what is it that you are having an issue with?